# Signal A is triggered at posedge of clock (40kHz), and it should go down to 0 during 1/4 of the clock

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

[image]

I have a clock which is 40 kHz. The Signal A is asserted '1' at the posedge of the clk. The Signal A should be deasserted to '0' as per the diagram. I have tried using

```
@(posedge clk) begin
   #(25/4) Signal_A <= 1;  // 40kHz = 25ns. 
         // We need Signal A to be 1 for quarter of that time period
end
```

Are there any other efficient ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

(25/4) Would not work as a delay because it is integer division.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
             Signal_A <= 0;
   #(25ns/4) Signal_A <= 1;  //40kHz = 25ns. We need Signal A to be 1 for quarter of that time period
end
```

Adding the `ns` does two things. It makes sure that `25` is interpreted in nanosecond regardless of that the current timescale is. And it changes the type from an integer to real, and the expression gets evaluated as real division.